# Jquery change the link to be from div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have those codes on my site (wordpress site) :

```
<div id="51" class="wrap-box">
<div class="favorit">
<a class="add" href="?wpfpaction=add&postid=51" rel="nofollow" ></a>
</div>
</div>
```

and this javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    $('.add, .remove').live('click', function() {
        dhis = $(this);
        wpfp_do_js( dhis, 1 );    
        return false;
    });
});
function wpfp_do_js( dhis, doAjax ) {
    url = document.location.href.split('#')[0];
    params = dhis.attr('href').replace('?', '') + '&ajax=1';
    if ( doAjax ) {
        jQuery.get(url, params, function(data) {
                dhis.parent().html(data);
                if(typeof wpfp_after_ajax == 'function') {
                    wpfp_after_ajax( dhis ); // use this like a wp action.
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

When a user clicks the link with the `class="add"` the video is added to favorite and the link changes to `<a class="remove" href="?wpfpaction=remove&postid=51" rel="nofollow"></a>` without changeing (or showing the ?wpfpaction... in the url) the website url the user is on ( the ?wpfpaction=add&postid=51 is executed but the page isn't changed ).
I want to change the code to be something like this :

```
<div id="51" class="wrap-box">
<div class="add" style="cursor:pointer;"></div>
</div>
```

How can i make this to be all from jquery and not to show the `<a>` tag anymore. So a user now clicks on the div `class="add"` the whole process to be the same, but from javascript.

Can this be done ?

Comment: `.live` is deprecated. What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: jQuery version is 1.7.1

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.add').on('click', function() {
    var link = $(this);
    var id = $(this).prev('.wrap-box').attr('id');
    var url = location.href.split('#')[0];
    var params = 'wpfpaction=add&postid=' + id + '&ajax=1';
    $.get(url, params, function(data) {
      link.parent().html(data);
      if (typeof wpfp_after_ajax === 'function') {
        wpfp_after_ajax(link);
      }
    });
  });
});
```